# No se esta colocando el valor a una variable global

Tags: php, curl

Tengo una variable global con un token ($acceso_final_global), debajo de la variable global mando llamar una función que obtiene llamadas (get_llamadas), al final de la función que obtiene llamadas mando llamar una función que inserta llamadas (insertLlamadas) y le paso como parámetro el token que declare arriba como variable global y el array de llamadas, pero el token que le pase como parámetro esta caducado entonces en un if de la función (insertLlamadas) estoy validando cuando el token ya valido o es incorrecto 2945 o 1030 para que genere uno nuevo, se lo coloque a la variable global y finalmente se vuelva a insertar los datos pero con un token correcto.

Todo lo esta realizando de manera correcta, pero cuando genero un nuevo token y se lo coloco a la variable global no lo esta haciendo porque al final del todos los procesos coloco un echo y en vez de imprimirme el token nuevo me está imprimiendo el viejo.

Espero que me puedan apoyar

> Código

```
$acceso_final_global = "1000.39022ce49e58bf4f67d0e2f3db83325c.62cd7d6bf688cd5a4e45a7c61b52a2df";

get_llamadas($array_cuentas);

function get_llamadas($array_cuentas){
    //Aqui obtengo las llamadas y mando ese array de llamadas
    global $acceso_final_global;
    insertLlamadas($data_json, $acceso_final_global);
};

function insertLlamadas($data_json, $acceso_final_global){
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://creator.zoho.com/api/v2/nombre/zoho-cdr/form/insert_final",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data_json),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken ".$acceso_final_global,
      "Content-Type: text/plain",
      "Cookie: 442b5845d7=f0ca98fc689b02462286b17d3e437fd5; zccpn=d38dce44-b631-4b67-9159-f870c828636a; _zcsr_tmp=d38dce44-b631-4b67-9159-f870c828636a; ZCNEWLIVEUI=true"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);

  if ($response === false){
      print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
  }

  $response = json_decode($response);
    if ($response->code == 1030 || $response->code == 2945) {
      // Aqui estoy obteniedo un token nuevo y si lo esta generando bien pero no se lo esta asignando a la variable global
      $acceso_final_global = conexion_dos();
      //Mando llamar nuevamente a la funcion que inserta llamadas pero con un token que no esta caducado
      insertLlamadas($data_json);
  }

  curl_close($curl);
}

//Aqui deberia de imprmirme el nuevo token que se le agino, pero me esta imprimiendo el viejo (1000.39022ce49e58bf4f67d0e2f3db83325c.62cd7d6bf688cd5a4e45a7c61b52a2df)
echo('</br>');
echo('Ultimo token: '.$acceso_final_global);
echo('</br>');
```

Comment: El error es simple no estás haciendo la asignación del valor a la variable global. Cuando asignas el valor lo asignas a una variable local situada dentro del ámbito de la función insertLlamadas()

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que no basta con declarar una variable como global para que efectivamente lo sea en todos los ámbitos.

Cuando la usas dentro del método `insertLlamadas()` la estás **redeclarando** en su signatura como variable local para el método. Si deseas modificarla allí tienes dos opciones:

1. declararla como pasada por referencia.
2. No ponerla en la signatura del método y usar la clave global para declararla al iniciar el método. En este caso la variable ha debido ser definida como global cuando se declaró por primera vez. Cosa que tampoco hiciste.

Ilustro las soluciones:

```
<?php
// Para que la variable sea efectívamente global debe declararse como tal
global $acceso_final_global = "1000.39022ce49e58bf4f67d0e2f3db83325c.62cd7d6bf688cd5a4e45a7c61b52a2df";

// Ahora, en el método get_llamadas() si se está accesando 
// si pruebas a ponerle un echo o var_dump a lo que tenías te debe 
// dar algún error

// Enfoque 1.
function insertLlamadas($data_json, &$acceso_final_global){
    // tu código debe mostrar el echo que esperas
    // Observa el & para pasar por referencia la variable
}

// Enfoque 2. 
function insertLlamadas($data_json){
    // declara la variable global para hacerla visible en el ámbito
    // del método
    global $acceso_final_global;
    // sigue tu código.
}
?>
```